# Collapsing duplicates in R where only the unique column values get condensed

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I need to collapse a large table (5M by V19) where I remove duplicates based on a specific column (V1), combine the values of all other columns if unique (if not, then report the result only once).

I've tried some solutions from here but those examples were mostly performed on 2 variables - I have 19. What ends up happening is that entire rest of the table gets omitted as it is summarized by just a specific variable, as opposed to applying the collapse to all columns.

Input:

```
V1         V2         V3         V4         V5         V6
TR1000     chr1       1000       1200       A          + 
TR1000     chr1       1100       1200       B          + 
TR1000     chr1       1000       1200       C          +  
TR2000     chr2       2000       2500       D          +   
TR2000     chr2       2100       2500       E          + 
TR3000     chr3       3000       3500       F          + 
TR3000     chr3       3000       3500       F          +
```

I Need:

```
V1         V2         V3              V4         V5        V6
TR1000     chr1       1000|1100       1200       A|B|C     + 
TR2000     chr2       2000|2100       2500       D|E       +  
TR3000     chr3       3000            3500       F         +
```

Comment: in base R `aggregate(.~V1, df, \(x)paste0(unique(x), collapse = "|"))`

Answer (score 4):

You may try this way using `dplyr`

## Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "V1         V2         V3         V4         V5         V6
TR1000     chr1       1000       1200       A          + 
TR1000     chr1       1100       1200       B          + 
TR1000     chr1       1000       1200       C          +  
TR2000     chr2       2000       2500       D          +   
TR2000     chr2       2100       2500       E          + 
TR3000     chr3       3000       3500       F          + 
TR3000     chr3       3000       3500       F          + 
", header =T)
```

## Code

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~paste0(unique(.), collapse = "|")))


  V1     V2    V3        V4    V5    V6   
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 TR1000 chr1  1000|1100 1200  A|B|C +    
2 TR2000 chr2  2000|2100 2500  D|E   +    
3 TR3000 chr3  3000      3500  F     +
```